# AWS API Gateway endpoints using basic authentication

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, basic-authentication, amazon-sqs, aws-api-gateway

Is it possible to expose an API endpoint in AWS API Gateway using basic authentication ?

Basically, an API endpoint which can be accessed using username and password ?

Further I want to take the user's payload to a SNS Topic / SQS queue. ( Customer with Username & Password -> AWS GATEWAY API -> SQS/SNS)

I am seeing quite lot of articles on how to expose using JWT's , but not using basic authentication.

Regards
Guru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AWS proxy integration method on API Gateway to put the payload into SQS from the API endpoint. Basic authentication is currently not supported by API Gateway.

Comment: "Basic authentication is currently not supported by API Gateway". So sad. Is there a different methodology to create a secure login to endpoint? Or in other words: is there a different htaccess methodology?

Answer (score 1):

you can create a dummy endpoint in the API Gateway, and create a Lambda function to authorize it handle the login logic  inside that authorization lambda function.

Note: it works but not an good practice